# How can I add a child at a position other than 0,0?

Tags: actionscript-3

How do I add a child to a position other than the upper left hand corner?

When I press my button the child appears upper left, when I press it again it appears at the coordiantes i have.

Is there anyway to change this initial position?

Comment: Please add the relevant codes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change an object's position before you add it to scene. After you add them, objects appear at 0,0 not because it is the default position, but because you haven't adjusted their *x* and *y* **properties.** Flashplayer places objetcs according to their positioning properties. And they are set to 0 *as default.*

```
var childObj = new SomeClass();
childObj.x = 100;
childObj.y = 100;
addChild(childObj);
```